# MySQL not appearing in PHPInfo

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, php

So I installed mysql on my linux box and I can login into it using the command line I can create a database, table, all that

I made a phpinfo() script and ran it, but it doesn't seem to recognize that MySQL is installed, am I missing a step here?

The info page returns all other information, which appears to be correct,

any advice would help thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using Amazon Linux AMI release 2010.11.1 (beta), Fedora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the php-mysql package.